# Connect to the mongodb service in EC2 in aws under windows, you can connect, but cannot connect successfully in Linux

Tags: mongodb, amazon-ec2

I use windows to connect to the mongodb in the EC2 server locally, the port is 23000, the connection is successful, and it is easy. But when I put the code on centos7.6 to execute it, I reported a connection timeout error. What is the reason? I also turned off the firewall of the centos server.

Comment: can you post the error.

Comment: do you have 2 instances? one for mongodb on windows, and centos. what do you have on these servers

Answer (score 0):

Check to see if your mongo db instance is allowing traffic from linux server. You have to check the security group of the instance.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I would like to ask which setting of the security group will cause this problem?

Comment: and i get another message is: in windows,use PHP can not connect the mongodb, either.

Comment: your mongodb runs on an EC2, and your linux server runs on an EC2. The security group of mongo db ec2 should allow the traffic from the linux server